# Проблема с десериализацией из XML

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

Помогите разобраться с десериализацией.

Создал XML, хочется именно такой вид, но не получается его распарсить. Все время теряется верхний уровень иерархии

**XML**

```
<calc xmlns="calc.xsd" version="1.0">
    <node name="Геометрия">
        <node name="Объемы"></node>
    </node>
</calc>
```

**calc**

```
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("calc", Namespace = "calc.xsd")]
    public class CalcTemplate
    {
        [XmlArray("node")]
        [XmlArrayItem("node")]
        public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [XmlAttribute("version")]
        public string Version
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

**node**

```
    [XmlRoot("calc", Namespace = "calc.xsd")]
    public class Node
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string Name
        {
            get; set;
        }

        [XmlArray("node")]
        [XmlArrayItem("node")]
        public ObservableCollection<Node> Children
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Верхним уровнем иерархии становится раздел "объемы", а первый почему-то пропускается. Чувствую, что ошибка где-то в описании calc, но не понимаю в чем. Если атрибуты убрать, то само собой, вообще пустой список приходит.

Десериализую так:

```
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CalcTemplate));
            template = (CalcTemplate)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            xmlReader.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
[XmlRoot("calc", Namespace = "calc.xsd")]
public class Node
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [XmlElement("node")]
    public ObservableCollection<Node> Children
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}



[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("calc", Namespace = "calc.xsd")]
public class CalcTemplate
{   
    [XmlElement("node")]
    public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("version")]
    public string Version
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: и снова вы меня выручили. Премного благодарен!

Comment: @pincher1519 пожалуйста :)